# How to run an app on Android L OR on 4.4 with Android Studio?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

I'm starting out with Android development and trying to play around with a test app on Android L.

I want to be able to load the material design theme on the Android L emulator, and standard holo theme on my Android 4.4 emulator. I just really can't get it running.

When I try and run the app I'm getting this error:

```
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material'.
```

My gradle file is like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.blitzcomputerservices.equinehealth'
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0'
    }

    productFlavors {
        l {
            minSdkVersion 'android-L'
            targetSdkVersion 'L'
            compileSdkVersion 'android-L'
        }
        old {
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 20
            //TODO comment second line if build is not compiles for "L"
            compileSdkVersion 20
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:1.1.5'
    compile 'com.soundcloud.android:android-crop:0.9.9@aar'
    /*lCompile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.+'
    oldCompile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0'*/
}
```

And the manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.blitzcomputerservices.equinehealth">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.blitzcomputerservices.equinehealth.EquineHealthActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
        android:name="com.blitzcomputerservices.equinehealth.HorseDetails"
        android:parentActivityName="com.blitzcomputerservices.equinehealth.EquineHealthActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_horse_details" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.soundcloud.android.crop.CropImageActivity" />
</application>
```

I have two `styles.xml` files:

One in `values` with:

```
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

and another in values-v21 with:

```
   <!-- Base application theme. -->
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
       <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
   </style>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> and another in values-v21 with:

The L preview is API 20, not v21

Comment: Was that a typo or am I missing something?

Comment: I just tried adding a `values-v20` folder with `<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>` and get the same error.. if that's what you meant. Not sure if I'm misreading it.

Comment: are you running on a device with the L-preview image installed? i.e. a Nexus 5 or Nexus 7?

Comment: @gmail All official android examples are with values-21.

Comment: @gmale I'm using the emulator, setup to run Android L. I also want it to run on an emulator running 4.4 though (but obviously without Android L "features" like material design, it should just fall back to Holo on those. It doesn't load/compile for either though.

Comment: hmmm. very odd. I'm going to put L on my Nexus 7 soon--after I get around to backing it up. In that process, if I figure out anything helpful, I'll let you you know. Hopefully, someone else will chime in and get you out of your rut. Sorry I couldn't be of more help!